# Filter one joined query with result of another query if result exists

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following tables:

*apartment*

```
class Apartment(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

*review*

```
class Review(models.Model):
    apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    review = models.TextField(null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    review_date = models.DateField(null=True)
```

*response*

```
class Response(models.Model):
    response = models.TextField()
    review = models.ForeignKey(Review, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    responded_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

*note*

```
class Note(models.Model):
    review = models.ForeignKey(Review, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    current_user = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(
      auto_now=True,verbose_name='Last Modified on'
    )
```

*unread note*:

```
class UnreadNote(models.Model):
    current_user = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    review = models.ForeignKey(Review, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    note = models.ForeignKey(
      Note, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
      verbose_name='Last Read Note'
    )
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(
      verbose_name='Modified Date Of Last Read Note'
    )
```

Here is the raw query that works fine:

```
SELECT rw.id, a.name apartment_name, p.id property_id, rw.review_date, 
un.modified_on modified_on 
FROM review rw LEFT JOIN response re ON rw.id = re.review_id 
INNER JOIN apartment a ON a.id = rw.apartment_id 
INNER JOIN note n ON n.review_id = rw.id 
AND n.current_user != 321 AND n.current_user IS NOT NULL
WHERE  rw.apartment_id IN (23, 432, 667, 123) 
AND rw.review_date BETWEEN '2023-02-01' AND '2023-04-30' AND 
GROUP BY  rw.id 
ORDER BY rw.review_date desc
```

Now I want to modify the above raw query by first converting the below ORM logic to raw query and then combining the two raw queries to get final query:

Here is the ORM logic:

```
def get_note_count_by_review(review_id, user_id, start_date="", end_date=""):
    unread_note = UnreadNote.objects.filter(
       review_id=review_id, current_user=user_id
    ).order_by("-modified_on").first()
    fields = {'review_id': review_id}
    fields.update({
         'modified_on__gt': unread_note.modified_on} if unread_note 
         else {}
    )
    fields.update(
        {'review__review_date__gte': start_date,
        'review__review_date__lt': end_date} 
        if start_date and end_date else {}
    )
    unread_note_count = Note.objects.filter(**fields).exclude(
       current_user=user_id
    ).exclude(
       current_user__isnull=True
    ).count()
    return unread_note_count
```

I tried to modify the original query by converting the ORM logic to sub query and add that in the original query here is final query:

```
SELECT rw.id, a.name apartment_name, p.id property_id, rw.review_date, 
un.modified_on modified_on 
FROM review rw LEFT JOIN response re ON rw.id = re.review_id 
INNER JOIN apartment a ON a.id = rw.apartment_id 
INNER JOIN note n ON n.review_id = rw.id 
AND n.current_user != 321 AND n.current_user IS NOT NULL 
AND modified_on > (SELECT modified_on FROM 
unread_note WHERE current_user=321 ORDER BY modified_on LIMIT 1)
WHERE  rw.apartment_id IN (23, 432, 667, 123) 
AND rw.review_date BETWEEN '2023-02-01' AND '2023-04-30' AND 
GROUP BY  rw.id 
ORDER BY rw.review_date desc
```

This doesn't work. I am not sure what the actual equalent query for the ORM would be also subquery is not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, what I understood is that you want to get the number of count of Notes for a single user where the `Note.modified_on` is greater than `UnReadNote.modified_on`. You can do that like this:

```
Note.objects.filter(user=user,review_id=review_id).annotate(max_unread_time=Max('unreadnote__modified_on')).filter(modified_on__gt=F('max_unread_time')).count()
```

Here I am using the reverse relation between `UnreadNote` --> `Note`, and annotating the `Max` value of the `UnReadNote.modified_on` and making a filter then count the number of `Note`s.

---

For getting `Review` with more than 0 unread notes based on business logic mentioned above, you can try like this:

```
queryset = Note.objects.annotate(unread_time=Max('unreadnote__modified_on')).filter(modified_on__gte=F('unread_time')).values('review').annotate(count=Count('pk')).filter(count__gt=0).values('review', 'count')
```

If you want to get the raw query of the queryset, you can try like this:

`str(queryset.query)`

Comment: Thanks for the response but i want the raw query so that i can attach it with original query to get only those reviews whose count is greater than 0.

Comment: I don’t get it. do you want review counts which have more than zero unread notes? also fyi, django raw queries will be deprecated in near future, hence raw query is not a good idea

Comment: The first raw query I have added in the question shows me list of reviews for a particular apartment on a specific date range. But along with that I want to get only those reviews who have unread count greater than zero. The logic of calculating this count is defined in the function that i included in question. I want to first convert that count logic to raw query so that i can add it to original query to get the desired output. I am struggling to add the count query to the original query.

Comment: So there are two sides of the question first convert the ORM logic (that calculates unread count) to raw query. Second find a way to add this raw query into the original query without breaking the original query.

Comment: Can you check if the updated answer helps ?

Comment: Yes i check the first ORM you posted that gives wrong result. And the second one doesn't calculate for each `review_id` but for all.